# Google People API listDirectoryPeople not returning birthdays

Tags: typescript, google-api, google-workspace, google-apis-explorer, google-people-api

When I try to fetch directory people data using Google People API's method `listDirectoryPeople` like this:

```
const directoryPeople = await client.people.listDirectoryPeople({
  readMask: ['birthdays'].join(','),
  sources: ['DIRECTORY_SOURCE_TYPE_DOMAIN_PROFILE', 'DIRECTORY_SOURCE_TYPE_DOMAIN_CONTACT'],
});
```

The result that I get does not contain any birthdays data:

```json
[
  {
    "resourceName": "people/1129142197755918xxxxx",
    "etag": "%EgcBAj0HCDcuxxxxxxx"
  },
  {
    "resourceName": "people/1157503689313342xxxxx",
    "etag": "%EgcBAj0HCDcuxxxxxxx"
  },
  {
    "resourceName": "people/1075895504789707xxxxx",
    "etag": "%EgcBAj0HCDcuxxxxxxx"
  }
]
```

However, when I try to fetch a single person data from directory with this code:

```
const info = await client.people.get({
  resourceName: 'people/1177805363189588xxxxx',
  personFields: ['birthdays'].join(','),
});
```

I get a result that contains birthdays data:

```json
{
  "resourceName": "people/1177805363189588xxxxx",
  "etag": "%EgUBBwg3Lhoxxxxx",
  "birthdays": [
    {
      "metadata": {
        "primary": true,
        "source": {
          "type": "DOMAIN_PROFILE",
          "id": "1177805363189588xxxxx"
        }
      },
      "date": {
        "month": 12,
        "day": 22
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Could someone explain why `listDirectoryPeople` method does not return `birthdays` field even though it is a valid `readMask` value in API docs?

P.S. `searchDirectoryPeople` method returns `birthdays` field as well. But why `listDirectoryPeople` fails to do that?

Comment: bug report it maybe https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:344199%2B

Comment: @DaImTo alright, done: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/184830967